# Salesforce Bulk Upload API call using python

Tags: python, salesforce

I am working on the salesforce api and came across the Bulk Upload API. I want to upload some data from a database into salesforce using the Bulk Upload API with python. I am currently using BeatBox as the library. Any pointers on how can I proceed using BeatBox? or are there ways to go about it.
I have already done with half of the solution where in the data is queries from SQL and made into csv file. But how do I go about it after this for the BULK upload? Pointers would be of great help.

Answer (score 3):

Found this package a few days ago:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/salesforce-bulk/1.0.1

Seems like is what you're looking for:

```
from salesforce_bulk import CsvDictsAdapter

job = bulk.create_insert_job("Account", contentType='CSV')

accounts = [dict(Name="Account%d" % idx) for idx in xrange(5)]    
csv_iter = CsvDictsAdapter(iter(accounts))    
batch = bulk.post_bulk_batch(job, csv_iter)    
bulk.wait_for_batch(job, batch)    
bulk.close_job(job)    
print "Done. Accounts uploaded."
```

Answer (score 0):

I learned almost everything I know from this site. Really great examples:

http://tomhayden3.com/2013/08/04/salesforce-python/

http://tomhayden3.com/2013/09/05/salesforce-beatbox-multi/